# Ripping a CD: how to write ISRCs into ID3 tags?

Tags: sound, rhythmbox, cd-ripping

On professionally pressed Audio-CDs the ISRC (International Standard Recording Code) identifies any recorded track with 12 digits (like this: ATP811301008)
It's usually not part of the CD-Text that contains artist, title etc. 
One can read it with cd-info (part of libcdio-utils)

The data from CD-Text is used by Rhythmbox, Sound Juicer or k3b to fill the ID3 tags (or they get the data from cddb or MusicBrainz or something).

Is there any software in ubuntu repositories to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the repos, but there is a snap etc of a software called fre:ac.
fre:ac can be set to write the ISRC into a ID3-Tag labeled "ISRC".